# Error in getEndOffsetInclusive function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to delete all the text from a certain part of the document to the end of the document. However, when I run the the below code, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getEndOffsetInclusive in object Text. (line 79, file "Code")
```

The line in question is:

```
var endOff = text.getEndOffsetInclusive();
```

Below is the full function:

```
    function removeText() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var text = body.editAsText();
    var endOff = text.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    var search = "TESTHERE";
    var rangeElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText(search);
    if (rangeElement.isPartial()) {
       var startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
       var endOffset = text.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       rangeElement.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);
    }

}
```

Any ideas as to why it's giving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function does not exist on `Text` instances. But it does exist on the `RangeElement` object. Update your code to:

```
var endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was a really stupid mistake!